# Wordpress Dynamic Design Slidshow

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

I am in need of a wordpress plugin that will let clients add images for a slideshow on the homepage, but, is easily integrate-able into my design. (My design is just three divs, so I need it to cycle through the three divs)

I do not have much experience with Wordpress Slideshow plug-ins so I was hoping someone here knew of one that fits what I need!

Comment: @DavidChase yes I know jQuery

Comment: then use http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smooth-slider/
its a pretty easy to use slider